# How to compile C program using Clang and libc other than provided by system, eg. musl?

Tags: c, clang, libc, musl

According to clang's [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Toolchain.html#c-standard-library),

> Clang supports a wide variety of C standard library implementations.

But it lacks the information about how to actually use desired libc.

For example, how to use clang with musl if my system provides Glibc by default? Do I need musl-built clang itesl?

Comment: Looks like you need to use they own `gcc` build: https://www.musl-libc.org/how.html

Comment: https://libcxx.llvm.org//UsingLibcxx.html

Comment: Note that I'm interested in using differnt _C library_, not C++.

Comment: musl?  /////////

Comment: The `-stdlib=` option is available for both C and C++ compilations.

Comment: Have you compiled and installed musl on your system? `how to use clang with musl?` Normally, there is no difference. `Do I need musl-built clang itesl?` No, clang is separate to musl, they are separate things. You can build clang with any ABI-compatible compiler and build musl with any (different or same) ABI-compatible compiler. To use a different standard library than your systems default, specify `-sysroot=` or `-stdlib=` or similar options. I have no problems using clang on alpine system which uses musl. `How to compile C program using Clang and musl?` Just `clang file.c`

Answer (score 0):

From official document of musl it may be not easy to do so.

You can try to link against `libc.so` or `libc.a` in your musl install path, and instruct clang not to link standard libc. Also you need some way to let it include headers form musl's `include` path.

There can be problems. I'm not sure if gcc-targeted musl can work fine with clang compiled object.

And here's someone's work that may help:
https://github.com/dslm4515/CMLFS

Comment: > I'm not sure if gcc-targeted musl can work fine with clang compiled object. By "gcc-targeted musl" do you mean "musl built with gcc"? Does it mean that I need clang-compiled musl as well?

Comment: Why is this so? Isn't a machine code is just a machine code, no mater which compiler produced it? In the end, it just object files and symbols. Why all this is so difficult/interleaved/coupled?

Comment: BTW, musl provides `musl-gcc` and `musl-clang` wrappers, The former works just fine, and it uses something called "specs" (I'm not aware of what is this). The later seem to be "hacky" script which sets/unsets compiler and linker flags in unusual way. It doesn't work out of the box in my system.

Comment: by gcc-targeted I mean, in official document it suggests you to use special version of gcc(musl-gcc) to compile. from that I guess it may require some gcc specific feature to link.

Comment: > Isn't a machine code is just a machine code...  Real world can be more complex, E.g. calling convention can be different. Without pratice I can't tell if it works.

Comment: maybe `musl-clang` just does what listed above. can you post some output of your `musl-clang`?

Comment: AFAIK, calling convention is defined in ABI. Both GCC and Clang targeting Linux use same ABI. Or I'm wron?

Comment: Compiler wrappers: https://gist.github.com/tribals/7cd0b4d5da9ef3a0d579d214f3e5cd91

Comment: Sorry that I cannot help. I'm less famillar to the musl than you.

Comment: I don't think I'm more familiar than you :)